# Prove that $A$ is dense in $\bf R$

Tags: real-analysis

Let  $A =\{\sqrt{m} - \sqrt{n }:     \text{$n$ and $m$ are positive natural numbers}\}$.

Prove that $A$ is dense in $\bf R$, 
I really can't find two natural numbers between $x$ and $y$.

I tried using $E(x)$ and $E(y)$ but with no good result.

Comment: What is $E(x)$ and $E(y)$? Also, note that $$\sqrt m-\sqrt n=\frac{m-n}{\sqrt m+\sqrt n}$$

Comment: I think $E(x)$ is an alternative notation for $\lfloor x\rfloor$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have any interval $(a,b)$ and want to show that it contains an element of $A$. Assume without loss of generality (why?) that the interval lies in the positive reals.

Let $\delta=b-a$, and select $n$ large enough that $\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k} < \delta$ for all $k\ge n$. (This is always possible because the difference between successive square roots converges to $0$ -- consider for example the derivative of the square root function and the mean value theorem).

Now, as you increase $m$ from $n$ and upwards in steps of $1$, the value of $\sqrt m-\sqrt n$ increases in increments of less than $\delta$. Therefore, at least one of these differences must fall within our initial interval of length $\delta$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $x\gt0$ and, for every $n\geqslant0$, consider $$m_x(n)=\lceil(x+\sqrt{n})^2\rceil,$$ then $\sqrt{m_x(n)}-\sqrt{n}\geqslant x$ and $m_x(n)\lt(x+\sqrt{n})^2+1$ hence $$\sqrt{m_x(n)}-\sqrt{n}\leqslant\sqrt{(x+\sqrt{n})^2+1}-\sqrt{n}\leqslant\frac{(x+\sqrt{n})^2+1-n}{\sqrt{(x+\sqrt{n})^2+1}+\sqrt{n}}\leqslant\frac{2x\sqrt{n}+x^2+1}{2\sqrt{n}},$$ that is, $$\sqrt{m_x(n)}-\sqrt{n}\leqslant x+\frac{x^2+1}{2\sqrt{n}}.$$ Thus, for every positive $\varepsilon$, if $n$ is large enough, then $$x\leqslant\sqrt{m_x(n)}-\sqrt{n}\leqslant x+\varepsilon.$$
If $x\lt0$, exchange $m$ and $n$.